# Lock every android app with unique password

Tags: android, encryption

Is there a way to lock every app i give to the end user with a unique password so that only i can generate a valid password to unlock that app and a copy of that app should not unlock with same password aswell.

I don't wanna setup online server for that. I need my app to be unlocked offline.

Comment: It might be possible, but you would have to distribute a customized or specially packaged app for each of your "customers" separately with a separate key. How do you plan on doing that without an online infrastructure?

Comment: You are right, app can be reverse engineered and can leak the algorithm. Thats what i am asking here. Is there any better, secure method?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate password on a first Application start using current time of system and Android Id, for example. Then you should show to user this time (that can be shown to them in some non-readable format) and his Android id. Then user sends you (or reads by phone, etc), this two lines and you combine them in a password using the same algorithm as phone did.

If the password can be long - create md5 hash of string, consisting of needed data. If it should be short - decrease the length of md5 or make some algorithm that will take only needed length from the whole password.

Comment: What about uuid?

Comment: I already have that kinda solution in mind but i am not satisfied with it.